# Excel VBA - Nested loop to format excel table columns

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a macro that so far, adds 4 new table columns to an existing table ("Table1"). Now, I would like the macro to format the 3rd and 4th row as percentage. I would like to include this in the loop already listed in my code. I have tried several different ways to do this. I don't think I quite understand how the UBound function works, but hopefully you can understand what I am trying to do.

I also am unsure if I am allowed to continue to utilize the WITH statement in my nested For loop in regards to me 'lst' variable.

@Jeeped - I'm looking at you for this one again...thanks for basically walking me through this whole project lol

```
Sub attStatPivInsertTableColumns_2()

Dim lst As ListObject
Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim colNames As Variant, r1c1s As Variant 
Dim h As Integer, i As Integer

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

colNames = Array("AHT", "Target AHT", "Transfers", "Target Transfers")
r1c1s = Array("=([@[Inbound Talk Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Hold Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Wrap Time (Seconds)]])/[@[Calls Handled]]", "=350", "=[@[Call Transfers and/or Conferences]]/[@[Calls Handled]]", "=0.15")

With lst
For h = LBound(colNames) To UBound(r1c1s)
    .ListColumns.Add
    .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = colNames(h)
    .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = r1c1s(h)
  If UBound(colNames(h)) = 2 or UBound(colNames(h)) = 3 Then        
        For i = UBound(colNames(h), 2) To UBound(colNames(h), 3)
            .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).NumberFormat = "0%"
  End if
        Next i
Next h
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest a second `for` loop.  If you want to set the 3rd and 4th columns to a percentage, you only need to set that when the iteration of the loop (`h`) is 2 or 3 (remembering that arrays index from 0).  You also shouldn't cross arrays for the main loop, and since `LBound` is in most cases 0 you might as well just use that anyway.  Try this:

```
With lst
    For h = 0 To UBound(r1c1s)
        .ListColumns.Add
        .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = colNames(h)
        .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = r1c1s(h)
        If h = 2 or h = 3 Then        
                .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).NumberFormat = "0%"
        End if
    Next h
End With
```

To answer the other point in your question, `UBound(array)` just gives the index of the largest element (the Upper BOUNDary) in the given array.  So where you have 50 elements in such an array, `UBound(array)` will return 49 (zero based as mentioned before).  `LBound` just gives the other end of the array (the Lower BOUNDary), which is generally zero.